# Are two events $ A$ and $B$ with $A \cup B = \Omega$ and P(A), P(B) $\lt 1$ automatically independent?

Tags: probability-theory

I think it must be really simple to solve this but I just can't seem to get it. I think you have to use $|\Omega | = |A| + |B| - |A \cup B |$ to show $\frac{|A \cup B |}{|B|}=\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$

Any tipps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- on the contrary they are automatically *dependent*, in that $P(A\mid \neg B)=1\ne P(A)$.

That is, unless either $P(A)$ or $P(B)$ is $0$ (since an event with probability zero is independent of *everything*).

Comment: how do you get from $P(A\mid \neg B) \ne P(A)$ to $P(A\mid B) \ne P(A)$

Comment: @DeltaChief: In general we have $P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid\neg B)P(\neg B)=P(A)$. If $P(A\mid B)$ equaled $P(A)$, its value would be a (nontrivially) weighted average of _itself_ and one different number, which is absurd.

Comment: @see: It is said that $A\cup B=\Omega$; therefore $B^\complement \subseteq A$.

Comment: @see: No: when $B^\complement\subseteq A$ we have $A\cap B^\complement=B^\complement$, not $A$, so your second equals sign is wrong.